# remove list-items with Linq when List.property = myValue

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
List<ProductGroupProductData> productGroupProductDataList = FillMyList();
string[] excludeProductIDs = { "871236", "283462", "897264" };
int count = productGroupProductDataList.Count;

for (int removeItemIndex = 0; removeItemIndex < count; removeItemIndex++)
{
   if (excludeProductIDs.Contains(productGroupProductDataList[removeItemIndex].ProductId))
   {
       productGroupProductDataList.RemoveAt(removeItemIndex);
       count--;
   }
}
```

Now i want to do the same with linq. Is there any way for this?

The second thing would be, to edit each List-Item property with linq.

Comment: This code would skip entries... If you remove the item at index 0 then it would not check the item that was at index 0 because it has moved to index 0 and you are now checking index 1!

Comment: What do you mean by "The second thing would be, to edit each List-Item property with linq"?

Comment: LINQ is side effect free so you can't remove items with LINQ you can create a new list without the entries would that suffice?

Comment: @Rune FS: Yes that could be a good idea. After that i can overwrite my old List with the new one.

Comment: @Bob Vale: It is a second question, maybe i ask it in a separate task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly corrected version of your current code that won't skip entries

```
List<ProductGroupProductData> productGroupProductDataList = FillMyList(); 
string[] excludeProductIDs = { "871236", "283462", "897264" }; 
int count = productGroupProductDataList.Count; 

for (int removeItemIndex = 0; removeItemIndex < count; removeItemIndex++) 
{ 
   while (removeItemIndex < count && excludeProductIDs.Contains(productGroupProductDataList[removeItemIndex].ProductId))  {
       productGroupProductDataList.RemoveAt(removeItemIndex); 
       count--; 
     }
   } 
}
```

This linq code would do the job.

```
List<ProductGroupProductData> productGroupProductDataList = FillMyList();  
string[] excludeProductIDs = { "871236", "283462", "897264" };  
productGroupProductDataList=productGroupProductDataList.Where(x=>!excludedProductIDs.Contains(x.ProductId)).ToList();
```

Alternatively using paolo's answer of remove all the last line would be would be

```
productGroupProductDataList.RemoveAll(p=>excludedProductIDs.Contains(p=>p.ProductId));
```

What you mean by "The second thing would be, to edit each List-Item property with linq."?

Comment: Ok, i try it with RemoveAll. With the second question i meant: How to edit list item properties for all items in a list with linq.
`foreach (ProductGroupProductData prodGroupProdData in productGroupProductDataList)
                {
                    productGroupProductDataList[i].ShowProductInfo = false;
                    i++;
                }`

Comment: @XmlmXmlmX The foreach is the best way to do the change, you can use linq to filter your foreach (eg just add `.Where(p=>....)`  to your collection inside the foreach.  Your syntax in the comment is wrong though the correct version would be (and the var is optional you can use the strong type name if you wish) `foreach (var p in productGroupProductDataList) { p.ShowPoductInfo = false; }` If you look into parallel Linq (PLINQ) there is a ForAll extension method and Parallel.ForEach method.

Comment: `productGroupProductDataList=productGroupProductDataList.Where(x=>!excludedProductIDs.Contains(x.ProductId)).ToList();` worked very well, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

you could use [RemoveAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/wdka673a.aspx).

Example:

```
//create a list of 5 products with ids from 1 to 5
List<Product> products = Enumerable.Range(1,5)
    .Select(c => new Product(c, c.ToString()))
    .ToList(); 
//remove products 1, 2, 3
products.RemoveAll(p => p.id <=3);
```

where

```
// our product class
public sealed class Product {
    public int id {get;private set;}
    public string name {get; private set;}

    public Product(int id, string name)
    {                 
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment here's a version that creates a set that excludes the elements rather than removing them from the original list.

```
var newSet = from p in productGroupProductDataList
                  where !excludeProductIDs.Contains(p.ProductId))
                  select p;
```

The type of newSet is IEnumerable if you need (I)List you can easily get that:

```
   var newList = newSet.ToList();
```